# Can I write OCaml pattern match with "when" in this way?

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

I am new in OCaml and here is my original code:

```
  method vinst(i) =
  match i with
  | Set (lv , e, _) ->
       let (host, _) = lv in
        match host with
         | Mem _ -> 
          (  self#queueInstr [mkPtrLVal (addressOf lv) e];
            ChangeTo [])
         | _ -> SkipChildren
         ......
```

Because after pattern matching of `Set (lv, e, _)`, I still need to pattern match both on `lv` and `e`, so I am thinking to re-write it in this way ( to get rid of annoying begin...end block):

```
     method vinst(i) =
     match i with
  | Set (lv , e, _) when (Mem _, _) = lv -> (* see I re-write it this way *)
          (  self#queueInstr [mkPtrLVal (addressOf lv) e];
            ChangeTo [])
  | Set (lv , e, _) when (Lval (Mem _, _)) = lv ->
      (  self#queueInstr [mkPtrE (addressOf lv) e];
          ChangeTo [])
  | Set (lv , e, _) when (TPtr _) = typeOf e->
        (self#queueInstr [mkPtrE (addressOf lv) e];
          ChangeTo [])
  | _ -> DoChildren
```

I tried to compile it but

Error: Syntax error: operator expected.

occured...

So Basically it is possible to write it in this way?  If so, which part should I adjust?

==================update===============

Here is what I did just now:

```
method vinst(i) =
  match i with
  | Set ((Mem _, _), e, _) -> (* pattern 1 *)
          let Set (lv, e, _) = i in
          (  self#queueInstr [mkPtrLVal (addressOf lv) e];
            ChangeTo [])
  | Set (_, Lval (Mem _, _), _) -> (* pattern 2 *)
          let Set (lv, e, _) = i in
      (  self#queueInstr [mkPtrE (addressOf lv) e];
          ChangeTo [])
  | Set (lv , e, _)   -> (* pattern 3 *)
      begin
      match typeOf e with
      | TPtr _ ->
          (self#queueInstr [mkPtrE (addressOf lv) e];
            ChangeTo [])
      | _ -> SkipChildren
    end
  | _ -> DoChildren
```

Is it good enough? Is there any more elegant way?

Comment: Regarding your update, your `let Set ... = i` are in fact non-exhaustive pattern-matchings, as the compiler should have warned you (even if in that case you know that the pattern is the correct one). Triggering compiler warnings is rarely a good idea. The answer from Benoît Guédas using the `as` binder is the best solution in my opinion. A small optimization could be to use `Cil.isPointerType` instead of the locally-defined `isPtr`, but that's all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of deconstructing `i` again to get `lv` or `e`, you can use an alias with the `as` keyword. You can also define a function `isPtr` that returns a boolean instead of using `typeOf` directly:

```
method vinst i =
  let isPtr e = match typeOf e with
    | TPtr _ -> true
    | _ -> false in
  match i with
  | Set (((Mem _, _) as lv), e, _) ->
      (  self#queueInstr [mkPtrLVal (addressOf lv) e];
        ChangeTo [])
  | Set ((_ as lv), (Lval (Mem _, _) as e), _) ->
      (  self#queueInstr [mkPtrE (addressOf lv) e];
        ChangeTo [])
  | Set (lv , e, _) when isPtr e  ->
      (  self#queueInstr [mkPtrE (addressOf lv) e];
        ChangeTo [])
  | Set (lv , e, _) -> SkipChildren
  | _ -> DoChildren
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do further pattern matching on the left of `when` (to the right should be a `boolean`, so that would be an inappropriate place for further deconstruction of the tuples/constructors),

```
| Set ((Mem _,_), e, _)  ->  ...
```

Comment: Hi nlucaroni, thank you for your answer and I just did this way... but one problem is that in the third pattern, I have to check **typeOf e**, which can not directly put into any pattern (am I right?) Then I just use another match ... with in the third pattern ... Is it good enough?

Comment: With what you've provided you are correct. I have no idea what `typeOf e` does or how `e` is constructed to know if it can be matched directly.